# Connect Tableau to Athena on Mac OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, tableau-desktop

Tableau Version `2021.1.2`
Java Version
`openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20`
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9)`
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)`
I placed the driver under ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers, but consistently getting the error message as shown in the attachment.[Error Message from Tableau Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXmeH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are placing drivers in the wrong folders, you have to copy the `.jar` file inside the folder

*C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers*

If it doesn't exist you have to create it.

From the [Tableau Drivers download](https://www.tableau.com/en-us/support/drivers) page:

> Follow these steps to install the JDBC driver for Amazon Athena on
> your Windows computer:
>
> Download the JDBC driver (.jar file) from the Amazon Athena User Guide
> on Amazon's website. Move the downloaded .jar file to C:\Program
> Files\Tableau\Drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using Mac, so its ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers. But you are right, I need to create the Tableau/Drivers folder under ~/Library/. But still it's giving me the error.

Comment: I am not sure but I think that these drivers probably works only on Windows. I have MacOS as well but Tableau (in general) doesn't work well as on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it as
`/Users/<username>/Library/JDBC/AthenaJDBC42.jar`

Comment: No it said differently here https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers?edition=. But I tried the directory you provided it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unhide the hidden folder from the  account which you mainly sign in from your Mac because there is a *hidden Library folder* where you would need to put the appropriate jar file in that's located in the  folder.

My url was Computer/MacintoshHD/Users/myusername/Library

This is the Library directory where I pressed shirt+command+. to unhide it. There, you should be able to find an already created Tableau Folder which contains another directory known as Driver. You would need to place the appropriate jar file in the Driver folder.

Hope this helps!